# Get string value from togglebutton

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created `Togglebuttons` composed of three options, each with a different text. The user can only select one option from the three, identifying their gender in this case. I would like to pass the selected option as a String to the next page.

How can I get the value from the selection as a string?

My code so far:

```html
List<bool> isSelected;

// Initialize Set state for gender button toggle
@override
void initState() {
  isSelected = [false, false, false];
  super.initState();
}


final genderToggleButtons = Container(
  width: mq.size.width,
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: AppTheme.define().accentColor,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(10.0),
    ),
  ),
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      return ToggleButtons(
        renderBorder: false,
        color: Colors.white,
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: constraints.maxWidth / 3),
        fillColor: AppTheme.define().primaryColor,
        selectedColor: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(27.0),
            child: Text(
              "Male",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17.0,
                fontFamily: 'RobotoRegular',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
            child: Text(
              "Female",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17.0,
                fontFamily: 'RobotoRegular',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
            child: Text(
              "Non-Binary",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17.0,
                fontFamily: 'RobotoRegular',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        onPressed: (int index) {
          setState(
            () {
              for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                  buttonIndex < isSelected.length;
                  buttonIndex++) {
                if (buttonIndex == index) {
                  isSelected[buttonIndex] = true;
                  // Choosing gender will enable the next button
                  _enableBtn = true;
                } else {
                  isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
                }
              }
            },
          );
        },
        isSelected: isSelected,
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you want to start passing data around to pages, which is really any real app, you'll want to implement a state management solution. Here's how I'd do it using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get).

Similar solutions are available with pretty much any other state management ie. Provider, Riverpod, Bloc etc...

Here's a class where the string will get stored and updated based on the `ToggleButton` selection.

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  String gender = '';

  void selectGender(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      gender = 'male';
    } else if (index == 1) {
      gender = 'female';
    } else if (index == 2) {
      gender = 'non-binary';
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

Throw this in your build method of the page with the `ToggleButton`. This initializes the GetxController.

```
final controller = Get.put(Controller());
```

The for loop of your `onPressed` now looks like this

```
 for (int buttonIndex = 0;
      buttonIndex < isSelected.length;
      buttonIndex++) {
     if (buttonIndex == index) {
      isSelected[buttonIndex] = true;
      controller.selectGender(index); // calling method from GetX Controller class
      _enableBtn = true;
     } else {
       isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
       }
      }
```

And here's an example of how you'd access that String from anywhere else in the app. Same concept applies to any other variable that lives in that class.

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller =
        Get.find<Controller>(); // finding same instance of controller
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        // this GetBuilder widget rebuilds based on any updates to the GetX variable inside
        child: GetBuilder<Controller>(
          builder: (_) {
            return Text(controller.gender);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```